# Pass Props and Function in onPress React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm calling a component in my file so I made a function in parent component and want to hit this function `onPress` of child component `MenuItem` and I also want to hit `hideMenu` function from child component at same time. Please provide me a solution for it. Thanks

Parent Component

```
onView(){
    alert('Dairu');
}
{this.state.clientsList.map((item) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.caseItem} key={item.ID}>
            <Card style={styles.card}>
                <CardItem>
                    <Body>
                        <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.FullName}</Text>
                            <CustomMenu onView={() => this.onView()} />
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.EmailID}</Text></Text>
                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.ClientType}</Text></Text>
                        </View>
                    </Body>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        </View>
    );
})}
```

Child Component

```
hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
};
render() {
    return (
        <Menu
            ref={this.setMenuRef}
            button={<Icon type="Feather" name="more-vertical" onPress={this.showMenu} style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#555' }} />}
        >
            <MenuItem onPress={this.props.onView}>View</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Edit</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Delete </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    );
}
```

Comment: With react web, if your child component is `CustomMenu`, you can call ` hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
this.props.onView()
};

Comment: @mpc do not got your point

Comment: @ZaInKhAn can you tell me little more what are you trying to do?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I'm want delete the record `onPress` of child component `MenuItem` so for this I made a function in parent component and it works but I also need to hit `hideMenu` function from child component on same `onPress`.

Answer (score 0):

You've already passed the onView prop to the child object. Just call this method in the hideMenu method in the child component:

```
hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
    this.props.onView();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `this.props.onView()` on your **hideMenu** function

```
hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
    this.props.onView();
};
```

also, you can pass an argument to parent component like:

```
this.props.onView(arg1, arg2);
```

and in parent component:

```
onView={(arg1, arg2)=> onView(arg1, arg2)}
```